# set a start time and date to a dataset

Tags: r, time, time-series

I'm struggling with setting compute the time in my dataset.
The file is named as a time and date, so I did use this code make it as a starting date:
'''`df$time <- ymd_hms("2020-02-16 03:39:00")`'''
In my dataframe I have distance and speed , so to compute the time I should use this code:
'''`time <- distance*3600/ df$SPEED`'''
but the problem is that the new column is stable ("2020-02-16 03:39:00") instead of showing the moving in time.
any help please?

Comment: Are `time` and `distance` columns of the dataframe? You are referring to them as standalone objects, presumably vectors. It will be easier to help if you can share an example of data in a form we can load as code. For instance `dput(head(df))` would create a code recipe for us to see what kind of data is in `df`.

Comment: time is not. distance and speed are columns

Comment: Thank you Jon , the problem is solved now.